# mysql server keyring Plugin installation

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql server installed on linux ubuntu and I am trying to install the keyring plugin. I have edited the my.cnf file located at /etc. The file was intially empty so I added the below content to it

```
[mysqld]
early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so
```

After doing the server restart , I ran the below query in workbench and I get zero results

```
SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE 'keyring%';
```

I am trying to follow this tutorial
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keyring-installation.html

Answer (score 3):

This was resolved by having the value in the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf